# In a basic WPF project, how can I avoid making a wide scope class initialization?

Tags: c#, wpf, class, xaml

This is a very basic question, and I'm certain the reason I haven't found an answer is because I'm not 100% positive how to google it.

I have a very simple project, where I want to use a class that contains my info.

```
public class MyInfo
{
    public string name = String.Empty;
    public string ssn = String.Empty;
    public string dob = String.Empty;
}
```

very basic.

I have a xaml file with buttons, and I just want to set the value of the variables in my class, to the contents in my buttons.  Here's the xaml.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="name" Content="John Doe" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="name_click"/>
        <Button Name="ssn" Content="222-22-2222" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="ssn_click"/>
        <Button Name="dob" Content="June 1st 1992" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="dob_click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The problem I'm having, is that the only way I know how to do this (being a total C# noob) is by having my class initialization in a super wide scope.

For example, here's my cs file with comments on what I initially did, but not what I think should be done.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{

    public class MyInfo
    {
        public string name = String.Empty;
        public string ssn = String.Empty;
        public string dob = String.Empty;
    }

    //  If i create a class instance here like this
    //MyInfo  infoTest = new MyInfo();
    //  then I can just set the values in the click functions like 
    //infoTest.dob = dob.Content.ToString();
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void name_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //save name.content into MyInfo.name
        }

        private void ssn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //save ssn.content into MyInfo.ssn
        }

        private void dob_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //save dob.Content into MyInfo.dob
        }
    }
}
```

I would think it would be better to create an instance of my class in the MainWindow class, after `InitializeComponent();`, but then I'm not certain how to get my values into the class object with a closed scope.

Comment: the commented parts looks ok to me. you can have fields in your class and access them from methods so no problem.  you can do something like `MyInfo.name = name.Content;`

Comment: So it's not considered to be a bad practice to make my class object infoTest so widely scoped?

Comment: No. its totally valid. this way is the most common way. (also its not really widely scoped since its private field.)

Comment: It only strange that you're using the `Content` property of a button to fill the data.

Comment: Yes, it is strange, it was just a quick example I typed out to hopefully remove some confusion I had about scoping practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like this also you should use [`Auto-Implemented Properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) instead of public fields:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyInfo myinfo = new MyInfo();
    myinfo.Name = name.Content.ToString();
    myinfo.Ssn = ssn.Content.ToString();
    myinfo.Dob = dob.Content.ToString();
}

public class MyInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to set properties after click buttons you should try this:

```
MyInfo myinfo = new MyInfo();

public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Then:

```
private void name_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myinfo.Name = name.Content.ToString();
}
```

Comment: In my example I'm using click events to get those values.  How could I still use this click events to set the values in the example you gave?

Comment: @trueCamelType...Make this `MyInfo myinfo = new MyInfo();` global.

Comment: Ok, so I guess my comments were correct in the example I gave.  I just assumed that what I had done was incorrect.  I assumed making it global would be bad practice.

Comment: @trueCamelType You could also declare it private inside the class, or integrate your viewmodel through xaml and use the datacontext, many options here, the right way depends on your context ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another method of achieving this would be to make use of `Binding`.

```
public class MyInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
} 

public class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyInfo();
    }
    ...
```

And your XAML will look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Name="name" Content="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button Name="ssn" Content="{Binding Ssn}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button Name="dob" Content="{Binding Dob}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

This will allow you to avoid having to use `Click` events to set the properties of your object. You can find an excellent tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part).

Comment: two souls, one thought

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already been marked, but I'd like to give you another POV using **binding**. Which i prefer to separate GUI/Business layer.

Some code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class MyInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Ssn { get; set; }
        public string Dob { get; set; }
    }

    private MyInfo _myInfo;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _myInfo = new MyInfo();
        _myInfo.Name = "My name";
        this.DataContext = _myInfo;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("My name is '" + _myInfo.Name + "'");
    }
}
```

---

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="BindingExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Ssn}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Dob}" />
        <Button Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

It's even possible to update the TextBoxes from code *(without writing directly to the Text property)*, assigning your class. Using the `INotifyPropertyChanged`